# How to get click event of marker using MapBox SDK?

Tags: android, mapbox, marker, clicklistener

I am using MapBox SDK for offline map I have added multiple markers on map,
how to get click event for markers.
Is there any way to get click event of marker?

Comment: how u resolved your issue @BSavaliya

Comment: i have used ItemizedIconOverlay for marker click

Comment: i m trying to use only one location that is user' current location on device with marker

Comment: This issue still seems to be quite popular, so it's worth clarifying that this issue is resolved in more recent versions of the Mapbox Maps SDk and @vanshg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39027948/6282077) is the best way to implement markers that can be clicked multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution for marker click event in mapbox using a functionality provided by mapbox sdk called ItemizedIconOverlay.

I have done like following :

```
   public void placeGTMarker() {
        alMarkerGT = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        marker = new Marker("my Marker", "", latLng);
        marker.setMarker(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin));
        mv.addMarker(marker);
        alMarkerGT.add(marker);
        itemizedIconOverlayGT = new ItemizedIconOverlay(activity, alMarkerGT,
                new OnItemGestureListener<Marker>() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, Marker item) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, Marker item) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        mv.addItemizedOverlay(itemizedIconOverlayGT);
    }
```

We can perform any event on **onItemSingleTapUp** for single click and for long click we can use **onItemLongPress** method.

I have used in my application and it works great

Comment: have u  draw circle with zoom in animation in current location and on click it should zoom out that circle

Comment: i only want to show marker image on current location of user so usage of UserLocationOverlay instad of alMarkerGT in ItemizedIconOverlay  is not allowed ? how to overcome

Comment: i m failed to get markers click using above method ?

Answer (score 4):

You can set a MarkerClickListener on the MapboxMap

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

and then have your class/activity/fragment implement `MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener`

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In this approach you can't click same Marker twice one after another, it gets the first click but does not get other clicks on same Marker unless you click Map and then clic same Marker again.

Comment: Yeah, MapBox knows about this and I'm assuming they're working on it
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6099

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3176

Answer (score 4):

**MapBox v10** (Kotlin)

```
val annotationApi = mapView?.annotations
val pointAnnotationManager = annotationApi?.createPointAnnotationManager(mapView!!)
pointAnnotationManager?.addClickListener(object : OnPointAnnotationClickListener {
    override fun onAnnotationClick(annotation: PointAnnotation): Boolean {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Marker clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> Kotlin

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mapView1 = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
    mapView1?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView?.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->
    mapboxMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(object: MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
            override
            fun onMarkerClick(@NonNull marker:Marker):Boolean {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return true
            }
            })}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {

    if (destinationMarker != null) {
        mapboxMap.removeMarker(destinationMarker);
    }
    destinationCoord = point;
    destinationMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destinationCoord));


    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(RouteFinderNewC.this);
    List<Address> address;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName("Lahore pakistan", 1);
        if (address == null) {

        }
        assert address != null;
        Address location = address.get(0);
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(lat, lng);
        System.out.println("latitude and longitiude oof lahore ///////////" + lat + "  " + lng);
        originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originCoord.getLongitude(), originCoord.getLatitude());
        getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }




    Toast.makeText(this, "Kindly wait for finding suitable route for your.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    button.setEnabled(true);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);

}
```